# What is the ISO C++ way to directly define a conversion function to reference to array?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

According to the standard, a conversion function has a function-id `operator` *conversion-type-id*, which would look like, say, `operator char(&)[4]` I believe. But I cannot figure out where to put the function parameter list. gcc does not accept either of `operator char(&())[4]` or `operator char(&)[4]()` or anything I can think of.

Now, gcc seems to accept `(&operator char ())[4]` but clang does not, and I am inclined to not either, since it does not seem to fit the grammar as I understand it.

I do not want to use a `typedef` because I want to avoid polluting the namespace with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use identity

```
template<typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };

struct sample {
  operator identity<char[4]>::type &() {
    ...
  }
};
```

You are correct that function and array declarators won't work in conversion functions. This is also known and discussed in [this issue report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#395). However i think that C++0x already provides a solution to what they discuss there

```
struct sample {
  template<typename T>
  using id = T;

  template<typename T, int N>
  operator id<T[N]> &() {
    ...
  }
};
```

Unlike the `identity` and `typedef` approach, this allows `T` and `N` to be deduced, i think.

Comment: Well, I guess `alias` is *technically* not a typedef, but... :argh:

Comment: Huh, I love how terse that `id` template is.

Answer (score 4):

C++ provides no syntax for that. This is one of those cases when you *have* to use a typedef-name for the type.

In order to avoid polluting the namespace, it is perfectly OK to declare the typedef-name inside the class

```
struct S {
  int a[4];

  typedef int A[4];
  operator A&() { return a; }
};
```